# Make forms inside a form catch focus when clicked

Tags: forms, delphi

In Delphi, you can create a Form inside another form by changing the TForm.Parent property.

There are two approaches to making a form inside another form

### Normal Forms (`fsNormal`)

Here is a example of creating a form inside a form

```
  with TForm.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Caption := 'Test 1';

      Width := 350;
      Height := 200;

      Show;
    end;
```

The problem is that they do not act properly when interacting with them. Catching focus only works by clicking on the title bar, or using Form.SetFocus, and the same is for the controls they contain. The forms will appear above any TWinControls or TGraphicControl that the form may contain.

[image: example of form inside form]

### MDI Forms ('fsMDIChild')

The *correct* way to do this is by using MDI forms. Like this:

```
  Form.Style := fsMDIForm;

  with TForm.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Caption := 'Test 1';

      Width := 350;
      Height := 200;

      FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
      Show;
    end;

  with TForm.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Caption := 'Test 2';

      Width := 350;
      Height := 200;

      FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
      Show;
    end;
```

And than the forms will act normally. Like this:
[image: example of mdi forms working]

### The problem

MDI forms would work perfectly for my use case, if not for 2 issues:

1. The `fsMDIForm` border, called "ClientEdge"
2. Controls inside the form appear above the MDI forms

The first issue can easily be solved by overriding `ClientWndProc`. The process goes like this:

```
procedure ShowMDIClientEdge(ClientHandle: THandle; ShowEdge: Boolean);
var
  Style: NativeInt;
begin
  if ClientHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    Style := GetWindowLong(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    if ShowEdge then
      if Style and WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0 then
        Style := Style or WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
      else
        Exit
    else if Style and WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE <> 0 then
      Style := Style and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    else
      Exit;
    SetWindowLong(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style);
    SetWindowPos(ClientHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or SWP_NOACTIVATE or
      SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = $3F then
    begin
      ShowMDIClientEdge(ClientHandle, false);
      Exit;
    end;

  inherited;
end;
```

But the 2nd issue with the MDI forms appearing below the components I belive cannot really be fixed. Which makes the `fsNormal` method more appealing, if the forms were able to act normally and catch focus that is.

In short, I need a form inside another form which can:

- Stay inside the client area, so It cannot leave or be drawn outside the client
- Appear above controls inside the form
- Be focus-able

So why are the `fsNormal` forms unable to catch focus?

Comment: Have you considered using TFrame instead of TForm? TForm was never intended to be embedded as a child, except for MDI (although Delphi 12 reworked that). TFrame is specifically designed to be embedded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would use a frame, but I require the window to be mobile with snapping, window states and present a title bar. Preferably a titlebar that is able to inherit a VCL Theme title bar.

Comment: Would this help you: In case of `fsNormal` child forms, write an `OnMouseDown` event handler in which you call `Self.BringToFront` and `Self.SetFocus`.

Comment: @TomBrunberg That is a improvement. But unfortunately, when I click on a component on the form that no longer works. I also tried overriding WndProc, which unfortunately still didn't work

Comment: It should be quite easy to make it work inside `Application.OnMessage` event. Look for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and if needed `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`. Check the clicked control (or it's owner or traverse parents) and do what's suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your `fsNormal` setup first with Athens, and after that i tested it with Alexandria.

Child form OnCreate procedure I just added code where Form2 parent is set to Form1.

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Parent := Form1;
end;
```

On Alexandria Focus problem on clicking form else where than its title bar can be solved by bring it to front on it's `OnMouseDown` event.
D12 doesn't have this problem anymore.

```
procedure TForm2.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  BringtoFront;
end;
```

One annoying problem still remains, and that is when you directly move form on its title bar, it will remain under other child form until you click it. But i solved that problem on windows event `WMMoving` by adding `BringToFront` in it. Also you mentioned child forms shouldn't go out of Form1 bounds, and it can be also easily solved on `WMMoving` event.

```
procedure TForm2.WMMoving( var msg : TWMMoving );
  var
    moveArea : TRect;
  begin
    BringtoFront;
    moveArea := Form1.BoundsRect;

    with msg.DragRect^ do
    begin
      if Left < moveArea.Left
      then
        OffsetRect( msg.DragRect^, moveArea.Left - Left, 0 );

      if Top < moveArea.Top
      then
        OffsetRect( msg.DragRect^, 0, moveArea.Top - Top );

      if Right > moveArea.Right
      then
        OffsetRect( msg.DragRect^, moveArea.Right - Right, 0 );

      if Bottom > moveArea.Bottom
      then
        OffsetRect( msg.DragRect^, 0, moveArea.Bottom - Bottom );
    end;
    inherited;
end;
```

When using windows events, you need to add it on Form class too.

```
procedure WMMoving( var msg : TWMMoving ); message WM_MOVING;
```

Problem with child form not changing it to top when clicking button inside the form for example and not form itself still remains.
One option is to bring form in front when mouse is entering to form.

```
procedure TForm2.FormMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetFocus;
  BringtoFront;
end;
```

These work on D11 and D12, I don't have any older versions to test with.

Also this old component still works.

https://torry.net/components/forms/other/ttopmost

I hope this will help you to advance on your project.

Comment: This addresses most issues. But the Form `OnMouseDown` method fails, because It only gets executed when you click on the form client, so If you click on a control inside the form, It's unnoticed. Setting `OnMouseDown` for all controls to the same procedure would work, not ideal but functional. One last Issue that I believe cannot be fixed is the titlebar text not changing color when the form is focused, but you can't always have nice things. Thanks for your detailed response!

Comment: I added some sort of solution to answer to first problem.